# Appears that java is replacing my objects over another, how can I remedy this

Tags: java, object

The project is to create an application that models an ice cream shop, tracking the number of cartons opened and allowing two different scoop sizes, the professor wants it all split up into classes like I have it.

This is my main method, which creates and calls my scoop class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Creating Objects
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scoop scoop = new Scoop();
    IceCreamShoppe icecreamshoppe = new IceCreamShoppe();

    //Prompting user to define sizes of scoops and carton
    System.out.println("How big is the first ice cream scoop?(radius in cm's)");
    scoop.setScoop1(input.nextDouble());

    System.out.println("How big is the second ice cream scoop?(radius in cm's)");
    scoop.setScoop2(input.nextDouble());

    System.out.println("How big is the ice cream carton?(radius in cm's)");
    icecreamshoppe.setCarton_radius(input.nextDouble());

    System.out.println("How big is the ice cream carton?(height in cm's)");
    icecreamshoppe.setCarton_height(input.nextDouble());


    //Returns to user their set values and sets size of carton
    System.out.printf("Scoop 1: %.2f, Scoop 2: %.2f, Carton Radius: %.2f, Carton Height %.2f%n", scoop.getScoop1(), scoop.getScoop2(), icecreamshoppe.getCarton_radius(), icecreamshoppe.getCarton_height());

    //While statement that continuously prompts user which scoop they want to use, everything else is done in the IceCreamShoppe Class
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Which scoop would you like to use? (1 or 2) (0 = Exit)");
        int scoopNumber = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How many scoops would you like?");
        int scoopCount = input.nextInt();
        icecreamshoppe.serve(scoopNumber, scoopCount);
    }//end while
}//end main
}//class
```

Here is my scoop method, that calls itself, I think this is the root of the problem. The problem is that my scoop sizes keep on getting reset whenever I call the scoop class.

```
public class Scoop {

//Instance Variables
private double volume;
private double scoop1;
private double scoop2;

//Constructors
public double doScoop(int r) {
    System.out.printf("You want this%f", this.getScoop1());
if(r == 1) {
    volume = (Math.PI)*Math.pow(this.getScoop1(), 3)*(4.0/3.0);
    this.setVolume(volume);
    System.out.printf("%f", volume);
    return volume;
}
else if(r == 2) {
    volume = (Math.PI)*Math.pow(this.getScoop2(), 3)*(4.0/3.0);
    this.setVolume(volume);
    System.out.printf("%f", volume);
    return volume;
    }
else {
    System.out.println("Invalid Scoop Number!");
    return 0;
}
}



/**
 * @return the volume
 */
public double getVolume() {
    return volume;
}

/**
 * @param volume the volume to set
 */
public void setVolume(double volume) {
    this.volume = volume;
}

/**
 * @return the scoop1
 */
public double getScoop1() {
    return scoop1;
}

/**
 * @param scoop1 the scoop1 to set
 */
public void setScoop1(double scoop1) {
    this.scoop1 = scoop1;
}

/**
 * @return the scoop2
 */
public double getScoop2() {
    return scoop2;
}

/**
 * @param scoop2 the scoop2 to set
 */
public void setScoop2(double scoop2) {
    this.scoop2 = scoop2;
}
 // 
 }//end class
```

Here are the other two classes, I dont think they are the problem, but then again, what do I know?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IceCreamShoppe {

//Instance Variables
private double carton_radius;
private double carton_height;
private int cartons_used = 0;


//Constructors
public IceCreamShoppe() {
}

public IceCreamShoppe(double r, double h) {
    this.setCarton_radius(r);
    this.setCarton_height(h);
}

public int carton_used() {
this.setCartons_used(this.getCartons_used() + 1);
    return this.getCartons_used();
}

/*
 * Object to serve the ice cream, the only input is which scoop is supposed to be used.
 * @param s Sets the 
 */
public boolean serve(int s, int n) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scoop scoop = new Scoop();
    Carton carton = new Carton();
    int i = 0;
    //Checks which scoop the is being used
    if(s != 0) {
        double scoopVolume = scoop.doScoop(1);
        while(i <= n) {
            if((boolean) carton.hasEnough(scoopVolume)) {
                carton.remove(scoopVolume);
                System.out.println(carton.getContains());
                i++;
            }
            else {
                this.carton_used();
                carton.carton(this.getCarton_radius(), this.getCarton_height());
                carton.remove(scoopVolume);
                System.out.printf("Carton Empty, Total Cartons Used:%d%n", this.getCartons_used());
                System.out.printf("New carton contains: %.2f%n", carton.getContains());
                }
            }
        }
    else {
        System.out.printf("You have used %d cartons of ice cream, there is %.2f ice cream remaining in the current carton", this.getCartons_used(), carton.getContains());
        return false;   
    }
    return true;
}

//Getters and Setters

/**
 * @return the carton_radius
 */
public double getCarton_radius() {
    return carton_radius;
}
/**
 * @param carton_radius the carton_radius to set
 */
public void setCarton_radius(double carton_radius) {
    this.carton_radius = carton_radius;
}
/**
 * @return the carton_height
 */
public double getCarton_height() {
    return carton_height;
}
/**
 * @param carton_height the carton_height to set
 */
public void setCarton_height(double carton_height) {
    this.carton_height = carton_height;
}
/**
 * @return the cartons_used
 */
public int getCartons_used() {
    return cartons_used;
}
/**
 * @param cartons_used the cartons_used to set
 */
public void setCartons_used(int cartons_used) {
    this.cartons_used = cartons_used;
}

}//End Class




public class Carton {

//Instance Variables
private double contains;

//Objects

//Checks if the carton has enough remaining, if not 
public boolean hasEnough(double v) {
    if ((this.getContains() - v) >= 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    } } 

//Sets the carton size 
public void carton(double r, double h) {
this.setContains(Math.PI*Math.pow(r, 2)*h);
}

//After checking if there is enough ice cream, this will run, there is 
no check against going negative
public void remove(double v) {
this.setContains(this.getContains() - v);
}

//Getters and Setters
/**
 * @return the contains
 */
public double getContains() {
    return contains;
}

/**
 * @param contains the contains to set
 */
public void setContains(double contains) {
    this.contains = contains;
}
}
```

Comment: "I think this is the root of the problem" - and what is the problem ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Running `doScoop()` on an uninitialized `Scoop` isn't going to do much...

Comment: Could you be more specific about the issue? What does "much" according to you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing in your scoop object into your icecreamshoppe.serve method and then you are creating a new scoop object in your serve method.

You should pass it in:

```
icecreamshoppe.serve(scoopNumber, scoopCount, scoop);
```

and change your serve method as follows:

```
public boolean serve(int s, int n, Scoop scoop) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Carton carton = new Carton();
    int i = 0;
    //Checks which scoop the is being used
    if(s != 0) {
        double scoopVolume = scoop.doScoop(1)
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it, something like this may seem obvious, but to someone who is just learning, this took me forever. It's awesome to know the comp sci field has people willing to help out. :)

Comment: @ThomasWalker You are welcome!